# Do two separate connections using same credentials share a thread?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In the process of converting mysqli_ functionality in PHP to utilize PDO. I've done a few pages of a CMS for proof of concept, and that lead me down the rabbit hole of persistent connections.

To avoid rambling, essentially I'm making a connection to the mysql server using the old method of mysqli_connect, as well as creating a new PDO resource, however, I'm only seeing one open thread. Since they're both using the same credentials to connect, are they sharing the open thread? Any additional info is also appreciated.

Thanks!

Unfortunately the code is government owned, but I can post some condensed snippets if that helps.

Database class connect method:

```
try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host="._DBLocation.";dbname="._DBName.";charset=utf8mb4";
        $options = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                 => true
        ];

        $dbh = new PDO($dsn,_DBUser,self::db_pass(),$options);
        self::$conn = $dbh;
        return $dbh;

    }
    catch (exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The db_pass method grabs the password from a text file on a remote server. The class is just invoked via $pdo = CLASS::connect();

The mysqli connection is simmilar, however it's made once and was being stored in a session. Password is retrieved the same way and also uses preset constants for the db location and name.

```
$_SESSION['sql'] = mysqli_connect(_DBLocation,_DBUser,$passwordVar);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: can we see the code for how you init the mysql connection for both PDO and mysqli? (obvs hash sensitive data)

Comment: MySQL can support multiple connections from one source.
Try running `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on MySQL from both.

The results should show you current and recently ended connections.

Results will look similar to this.
`| procid | user | MyPC:49693    | metastore | Sleep   |    86 |        | NULL
| procid | user | MyPC:49694    | metastore | Sleep   |  1347 |        | NULL `

Comment: Both mysqli and PDO use the same driver backend. In the case of mysqlnd it's pretty likely they reuse and share the connection (regardless of persistent flag). See `mysqlnd.debug`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I've added a few condense snippets. Let me know if this helps. If not, I'll try to get you more information.

Comment: any reason why you are saving the connection resource in a session variable?

Comment: @r007ed That may be my issue. I was running processlist from a gui tool. Would that not show me all current connections on the server, or would running it in the code from both connect attempts yield different results?

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi We needed the connection to be carried across pages of a CMS. I suppose it was to eliminate the overhead of establishing the initial connection each page. I'm absolutely open to better practices!

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs When moving between pages, if you try to initiate the connection each time, will it detect the open thread and use that, rather than create a new connection entirely? The purpose of the $_SESSION was to attempt to eliminate that overhead, but if that's not the case, that was silly on my end haha. Or if that is the case, is there nothing inherently wrong with making a new connection to a remote mysql server each page?

Comment: @B.Clark it's encouraged to create the connection per script rather than access it in the $_SESSION :) (in fact it's common practice as well to destroy the connection at the end of the script)

Comment: 1) Does it matter if your experiment shows both using the same connection? 2) For your production solution you shouldn't be mixing and matching different APIs for the same task 3) Do you actually need persistent connections? They create lots of complications in web applications.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Perfect! I'll get that switched over. Just out of sheer curiosity, why is it encouraged? Is there just no benefit in keeping the connection open across the duration of the session? Thank you by the way. This has been a huge help.

Comment: @B.Clark cool cool and because it's more secure :) open connection = doorway to your database

Comment: @symcbean It really doesn't. Especially given the mysqli connection will be completely removed soon enough. I was just curious. 2. This is completely in our CMS template system in test. The goal is to completely port this over there and then start on our CMS systems individually. 3. Not at all, now that you mention it. I was just taught that making the connection each page created a lot of overhead. Seems that's not actually the case haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a DbHandler class and call the appropriate variable when you need it.

**Note: This is example code - you may need to alter to fit your codebase.**

```
class DbHandler
{
    protected $pdo;
    protected $mysqli;

    public function __construct($pdo, $mysqli)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }
}
```

then use it like this:

```
$dbHandler = new DbHandler(new PDO(.. pdo deets ..), mysqli_connect(.. mysqli deets ..));

print_r($DbHandler->pdo); # will output a PDO object
print_r($DbHandler->mysqli); # will output whatever mysqli is.. an array? Not sure
```

Comment: It's better to write a separate decorator or wrapper for both libraries, and then use a common interface for both of them.  That way you can interchange the code without issues.  Basically you call your decorated methods instead of using the library methods directly.  So `$wrapper->execute()`  would call `$pdo->execute()`  or `$mysqi_stmt->execute()`  That's a bad example but there are some methods with different names/usage, like result row counting.  You basically normalize them by using a common interface.  Then you can switch seamlessly in your application code.